# Install a R package permanently in Google Colab

Tags: r, package, libraries

I am using the -idefix- R package and I do not want to install it everytime I log into Google Colab. Is there any way of installing it permanently? Will it also be installed for other people if I share the notebook.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Like what you could do in a local computer, copy the source local R library to the target location. See some instruction in this [blog](https://blog.atusy.net/2021/08/30/quickly-install-r-packages-on-colab/) ( atusy.net )

---

Here are two CoLab notebooks to reproduce the import and export R library.

- [CoLab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YVbOBeD6WY_aHj7tbpKnp56kqt67Wq3a?usp=sharing) export local library
- [CoLab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1R3aZ8k2uhs9-RnP9rJWv2tRPAZZCPhds?usp=sharing) import local library

---

Here are some minimal snippets in this I/O process.

Open a CoLab notebook in Python,

```
# activate R magic
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Make the notebook available for R.

```
%%R
install.packages('tidymodels')
tar("library.tar.gz", "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")
```

Install the package `tidymodels`, and zip your library with installed packages.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Connect your google drive and make a copy for use in the future.

```
%cp library.tar.gz drive/MyDrive/src/
```

`drive/MyDrive/src/` is the path I choose, you can use another.

---

Next, you use this library in another or new notebook.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Connect your Google Drive.

```
%cp drive/MyDrive/src/library.tar.gz .
```

Copy it in your working directory.

```
!tar xf library.tar.gz
```

Extract the installed packages from the zipped file.

```
.libPaths('usr/local/lib/R/site-library/')
```

update the Library path and put it at the top ranking.

```
library(tidymodels)
```

Check, this package is of reuse

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, each virtual machine is recycled after you close the browser window or the session is longer than 12 hours. There is no possibility to install packages in a way that you can access them without installing them again (to the best of my knowledge).